# QEMU kernel for raspberry pi 3 with networking and virtio support

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, raspberry-pi, qemu, virtio

I used the QEMU(qemu-system-aarch64 -M raspi3) for emulating the Raspberry pi3 with the kernel from the working image.
Everything was working but there was no networking.

```
qemu-system-aarch64 \
   -kernel ./bootpart/kernel8.img \
   -initrd ./bootpart/initrd.img-4.14.0-3-arm64 \
   -dtb ./debian_bootpart/bcm2837-rpi-3-b.dtb \
   -M raspi3 -m 1024 \
   -nographic \
   -serial mon:stdio \
   -append "rw earlycon=pl011,0x3f201000 console=ttyAMA0 loglevel=8 root=/dev/mmcblk0p3 fsck.repair=yes net.ifnames=0 rootwait memtest=1" \
   -drive file=./genpi64lite.img,format=raw,if=sd,id=hd-root \
   -no-reboot
```

I tried to add this option

```
-device virtio-blk-device,drive=hd-root \
-netdev user,id=net0,hostfwd=tcp::5555-:22 \
-device virtio-net-device,netdev=net0 \
```

But there would be an error

```
qemu-system-aarch64: -device virtio-blk-device,drive=hd-root: No 'virtio-bus' bus found for device 'virtio-blk-device'
```

I have referenced some forum, and used the "virt" machine instead of raspi3 in order of emulating virtio-network

```
qemu-system-aarch64 \
  -kernel ./bootpart/kernel8.img \
  -initrd ./bootpart/initrd.img-4.14.0-3-arm64 \
  -m 2048 \
  -M virt \
  -cpu cortex-a53 \
  -smp 8 \
  -nographic \
  -serial mon:stdio \
  -append "rw root=/dev/vda3 console=ttyAMA0 loglevel=8 rootwait fsck.repair=yes memtest=1" \
  -drive file=./genpi64lite.img,format=raw,if=sd,id=hd-root \
  -device virtio-blk-device,drive=hd-root \
  -netdev user,id=net0,net=192.168.1.1/24,dhcpstart=192.168.1.234 \
       -device virtio-net-device,netdev=net0 \
  -no-reboot
```

There is nothing printed and the terminal was suspended. It means the kernel does not work with virt machine.

I decided to build for my own custom kernel.
Could anyone give me advice for options to build the kernel that works with both the QEMU and the virtio?